# adding extra-addons on odoo.conf on macos as an extra path for addons

Tags: macos, odoo-13

i'm using mac os and i already installed odoo13
i'm trying to add an extra-addons as a new path for my addons, the thing is i cant find the new modules when i update the apps.
i found the odoo-conf in this path odoo13/debian/odoo.conf
i did edit the file to be

```
[options]
; This is the password that allows database operations:
admin_passwd = admin    
db_host = False    
db_port = False    
db_user = odoo 
db_password = False    
addons_path =/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons,/user/raed/odoo13/addons,/user/raed/odoo13/extra-addons
```

but that doesnt work and the new modules doesnt appeared in the apps

will bery very appreciated if any one can help

thanks

Comment: Add the addons path to the [configuration file](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/reference/cmdline.html#configuration-file). Does `odoo13/odoo.conf` file exists?

Comment: thanks for asking
no its not exist in odoo13/odoo-conf
but its exist in odoo13/debian/odoo.conf

Comment: To create the config file in home directory, check the link above.

Answer (score 1):

In your home directory, there are a hidden file named .odoorc

This file is the file configuration for odoo, so open it with nano and add your path custom under addons_path variable and restart odoo.

You custom path will be load